# Find distinict elements in an array in $O(n)$ time

Tags: time-complexity, data-structures, hash-tables, pseudocode, linear-complexity

Given this pseudo-code that finds the number of distinct elements in the given array:

```
D(A) // A is an array of numbers
U_Size = 1
For i=2 to length(A)
                  U=?
  For j=1 to U_Size
    If A[j]=A[i]
     Then U = FALSE
      j = U_Size
   if U = TRUE
     Then U_Size = U_Size +1   
         A[U_Size] = A[i]
return U_Size
```

Time complexity for that alogrithm is $O(n^2)$

I will need to write 2 new algorithms for the same purpose in $O(n)$ according to one of each of the conditions bellow:

1. let's say that the numbers are integers only and inside the range of [$10,10n$], without using any sorting method
2. Now, there is no given range of numbers, and I can use any sorting method I want

> MY SOLUTION:
>
> for the first condition, I tried using HashSet, but I think it has a
> more sofisticated solution. My pseudo-code:
>
> ```
> countDistinctNums(int A[], int n)
>   hashSet hs = new Hashset   
>     for i=0 to n
>     // add all the elements to the HashSet
>       hs.add(A[i])
>
>     // return the size of hashset as it consists of 
>     // all unique elements 
>   Return hs.size();
> ```
>
> for the second one, a hash table will be the optimal solution but I
> think also one of the linear-sorting methods will be good enough

**My questions are:**

1. Does HashSet is a good solution for one of the conditions ( or both )?
2. How do I implement an HashTable for the solution of the second condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first task you can use a solution similar to yours.
Let the input array be $A[1, \dots n]$. Create an array $B$ indexed with the integers from $10$ to $10n$ where each entry is a boolean value initially set to false. Then, for each input element $A[i]$, set $B[A[i]]$ to true. At the end of the above loop, return the number of indices $y$ such that $B[y]$ is true. This runs in $O(n)$ worst-case time.

Notice that, depending on how the hashtable is implemented, a hashtable-based solution is not guaranteed to have a **worst-case** time complexity of $O(n)$. Usually the hash-tables provided by the common programming languages only provide you with **expected** constant time operations.

Also, if don't have any other information on the values the the input integers, you can't use linear-time sorting algorithms (since their complexity depends on the range of the input values).

Anyway, your solution already works for the general problem in $O(n)$ **expected** time.

I don't think the general problem can be solved in $O(n)$ worst-case time. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), there is a lower bound of $\Omega(n \log n)$ on the algebraic decision tree model, and randomness doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand the first paragraph implementation. What do you mean by: "for each input element $x$, set $A[x]$ to true" ? pseudo-code will be helpful too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the second task with $O(n)$ expected running time (average-case running time), if you use a hash table with a 2-universal hash function.  As far as I know, no deterministic $O(n)$-time algorithm is known.

Comment: Can you elaborate on Universal hash function?